# php mysql query connection error cannot select database

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I'm having some trouble making a connection to my database. As far as I'm concerned I'm using the same code as usual. But suddenly I can't seem to make a connection. I've tried the script locally using MAMP aswell as online on my server.

I use a config file to select and connect the database with the following code:

```
<?php
  $db_host = "localhost";
  $db_username = "root";
  $db_password = "root";
  $db_database = "dbname";
$link = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_username,$db_password) or die("Cannot connect");
  mysqli_select_db($link, $db_database) or die("Cannot select database");
  ?>
```

Next I try to print info from my database on my page using the following code:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM ditdoenweblokken ORDER BY id DESC";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error()) ;
while($rij = mysql_fetch_array($result)){  
$ID = $rij['id'];
?>
<li><a style="height:150px;width:150px;" class="fancybox" href="#inline1">
    <p style="font-weight:bold;"><?php echo($rij['titel']);?></p>
    <?php echo($rij['quote']);?></a>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
```

I've been staring my eyes out and don't know how to move on. Keep coming up with the same problem. If someone could help me out, it would be so much appreciated.

That's the error message:

> mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /public/sites/www.kernlab.nl/website/index.php on line 11
>
> Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: A link to the server could not be established in /public/sites/www.kernlab.nl/website/index.php on line 12
>   Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

Comment: are those php codes in the same file?

Comment: Are you combining `mysqli_` and `mysql_` functions? Is that really possible? Also, what's the error message? MySQL is like to [tell you why you cannot connect](http://de2.php.net/manual/de/mysqli.connect-error.php).

Comment: Check database service is running and any firewall settings is blocking data server.

Comment: I get
Warning: mysql_query() [function.mysql-query]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /public/sites/www.kernlab.nl/website/index.php on line 11

Comment: They are not in the same file. But the config file is included in the header of each page. So actually, yeah they are in the same file :P

Comment: mysql port 3306 is busy. this is not connecting with database

Comment: Are you using `mysql` or `mysqli`

Comment: I'm using both mysql and mysqli since some of the mysql functions I've been using we're deprecated. But I'm not advanced enough to edit everything to mysqli 

@ Moyed, what's the solution for that?

Comment: Is the MySQL service running correctly? You can connect to it from a normal program?

Comment: yeah it is. Both on my localhost aswell as my online server

Comment: Try to connect your database using mysql or mysqli once

Comment: Am i not? Not sure what you mean? Weird thing is, this is the way I've been doing it multiple times

Comment: Try using the local ip address `(127.0.0.1)` instead of 'localhost' in `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: tried it, makes no difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In config  you use `mysqli_` (mysqli extenton) methods.

Then you use `mysql_` (mysql extenton) methods.

You are using different extentions. Use same extention in both cases.